# Accessing Parsed CSV data , CSV-Parser Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

Im using csv-parser npm package and doing a sample csv parse. My only confusion is accessing the parsed array after running these functions. I understand im pushing the data in `.on('data')` , then doing a `console.log(results);` statement in `.on('end');` to show what's being stored. Why do I get undefined when i try to access `results` after running those functions. Doesn't `results` get the information stored?

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const results = [];


fs.createReadStream('demo.csv')
.pipe(csv())
.on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
.on('end', () => {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: remove the `()` from `csv()` call

Comment: I have just tried running your code and I have no issue with it (node v12.16.2).
Are your sure demo.csv is not en empty file ?

Comment: @RandyCasburn thank you for your comment, but i still get `Type Error: dest.on is not a function`

Comment: @A.DUPONCHEL demo.csv has two rows with a ID and Email column. I can get results in `.on('end', () => { console.log(results);}); ` , but if I put a `console.log()` after the `createReadStream` , results is undefined, does that make sense?

Comment: When you removed the `()` and got `dest.on is not a function`, that means the `csv()` function is not returning an object with an `on()` method. This most likely means `csv()` is not returning a Stream.

Answer (score 1):

I came here to find the solution to the same issue.
Since this is an `async` operation, what works here is to call that function that acts on your parsed data once the `end` handler is called. Something like this should work in this situation:

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const results = [];

fs.createReadStream('demo.csv')
.pipe(csv())
.on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
.on('end', () => {
    console.log(results);
    csvData(results);
});

const csvData = ((csvInfo) => {
    console.log(csvInfo);
    console.log(csvInfo.length);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can get results in .on('end', () => { console.log(results);}); , but
> if I put a console.log() after the createReadStream , results is
> undefined, does that make sense? – Videoaddict101

Your stream acts asynchronously, that means your `data` and your `end` handler will be called later, meanwhile your javascript continue to be executed. So accessing your array just after `fs.createReadStream` instruction will result of an empty array.

Understanding async is very important using javascript, even more for nodejs.

Please have a look on differents resources for handling async like [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) ...

Answer (score 0):

You should you [neat-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/neat-csv) which is the endorsed wrapper for `csv-parser` that gives you a promise interface.

That said, you can create a promise and resolve it in the `on("end", callback)`

```js
import fs from "fs";
import csv from "csv-parser";

function getCsv(filename) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const data = [];
    fs.createReadStream(filename)
      .pipe(csv())
      .on("error", (error) => reject(error))
      .on("data", (row) => data.push(row))
      .on("end", () => resolve(data));
  });
}

console.log(await getCsv("../assets/logfile0.csv"));
```